# AngularJS Directive dynamic class change not taking hold

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and have several menu items in a navbar, and what I want is essentially for the one that is currently selected for the page I am on to appear "highlighted" (have a dark background and white text). It is selected based off of the browser URL link comparison. This navbar "reloads" every time one of the links is clicked.

I cannot change how I approach this (ie. avoid reloading the navbar) due to requirements of the app I was given to work on.

```
<ul>
     <li>
           <a nav-bar-select ui-sref="page1" >Page 1  </a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a nav-bar-select ui-sref="page2" >Page 2</a>
     </li>
     <li>
            <a nav-bar-select  ui-sref="page3">Page 3</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

My issue is, I am able to dynamically change the `className` of a selected element, but the change does not reflect on my screen.

Here is my HTML view:

And here is my directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('navBarSelect', function ($location) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("Location path is: " + $location.path());
                console.log("Elem attrs.href is: " + attrs.href.substr(2, attrs.href.length));
                //URL load starts with '#!' in the URL, skip it in check
                if (attrs.href.substr(2, attrs.href.length) === $location.path()) {
                    console.log("elem matched here it is before: ");
                    console.log(element);
                    element.className = 'menuItem selectedMenuItem';
                    console.log("elem after: ");
                    console.log(element); // *1
                } else {
                    console.log("Elem did not match");
                    element.className = 'menuItem';
                    console.log(element)

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And here is the simple CSS that I want to take effect:

```
.selectedMenuItem {
    background: #37474F;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

When I run this, all of the elements get verified on each click, and the `after` console.log indicates that the `className` of the object takes up the change, based on how it got evaluated in the `if` statement. I've noticed the `console.log` marked with a `*1` comment when displaying, doesn't display a raw element, but instead displays on object holding the element. Does this have anything to do with it?
 Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is wrapped with jqLite (or jQuery, if it's loaded), so you may need to use `addClass`:

```
element.addClass('menuItem selectedMenuItem');
```

Comment: Thank. You. You have no idea how much this has helped.